# Adding another join in this sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

The below query takes around 3 minutes to complete. However the requirement is now to get another attribute in the SELECT which resides in a different table.

For which i believe i have to do another join here on the table ACCOUNT_CYCLE_ACTIVITY, but a simple join on the account_id here takes the time of execution from 3 min to more than an hour.

Any way to make this run faster?

```
SELECT *
 FROM ACCOUNT_CYCLE_ACTIVITY aca 
 inner join card_account ca 
    on aca.account_id = ca.ACCOUNT_ID
    and aca.ACTIVITY_TYPE_CODE in ('011', '021', '007') 
    and aca.ACTIVITY_GROUP_CODE= 'R12'
    and (aca.CYCLE_ACTIVITY_AMOUNT) > 25 
    and aca.CYCLE_ACTIVITY_COUNT =1
    and aca.cycle_ctr = ca.cycle_ctr - 1
 left join ACCOUNT_CYCLE_ACTIVITY aca2
        on aca2.account_id            = aca.ACCOUNT_ID
        and aca2.ACTIVITY_TYPE_CODE  = aca.activity_type_code 
        and aca2.ACTIVITY_GROUP_CODE = aca.activity_group_code
        and aca2.CYCLE_ACTIVITY_COUNT = 1
        and aca2.cycle_ctr between aca.cycle_ctr - 6 and aca.cycle_ctr - 1

where aca2.ACCOUNT_ID is null;
```

Comment: Somehow, I suspect that this query could be greatly simplified either by using aggregation or analytic functions.

Comment: If your query is running that slow I would suspect you don't have much in the way of indexing. I would take a look at what columns you are joining on and seeing if you cant put an index on them. SSMS can suggest some to you, but take them as a starting point, not a a solution

Comment: You could not use `SELECT *` and you could turn that left join into a `NOT EXISTS`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to work with your query, below is something promising. I eliminated `self-join` by using `lag()` (as @Gordon Linoff suspected in his comment) in first subquery and filtering on this virtual column in main query. Query returns same rows which return yours, but please compare on real data.

```
with aca as (
  select a.*, lag(cycle_ctr) over (
        partition by account_id, activity_type_code, activity_group_code 
        order by cycle_ctr ) as pcc
    from account_cycle_activity a 
    where activity_type_code in ('011', '021', '007') and activity_group_code = 'R12' 
      and cycle_activity_amount > 25 and cycle_activity_count = 1
  )
select aca.account_id, aca.cycle_ctr, aca.activity_type_code, activity_group_code
  from aca 
    join card_account ca 
      on ca.account_id = aca.account_id and ca.cycle_ctr - 1 = aca.cycle_ctr
  where pcc is null or pcc-aca.cycle_ctr not between -6 and -1
```

As for this part of your question:

> the requirement is now to get another attribute in the SELECT which
>   resides in a different table

I have to little information what should be done, please be more precise, edit original question if needed.

I think that indexes mentioned in comments are very important here, but without data access it is hard to say which are best.

Table structures and sample data I used are listed below. If you find any differences between your results and mine in your data please add some rows from both tables which produce this situation.

```
create table account_cycle_activity (
  account_id number, cycle_ctr number, activity_type_code varchar2(3), 
  activity_group_code varchar2(3), cycle_activity_amount number,
  cycle_activity_count number);
insert into account_cycle_activity values ( 1,   1, '011', 'R12', 30, 1);
insert into account_cycle_activity values ( 2,  12, '011', 'R12', 30, 1);
insert into account_cycle_activity values ( 2,   8, '011', 'R12', 30, 1);
insert into account_cycle_activity values ( 2,   8, '011', 'R12', 30, 1);
insert into account_cycle_activity values ( 2, 100, '021', 'R12', 30, 1);
insert into account_cycle_activity values ( 2,  98, '021', 'R12', 18, 1);
insert into account_cycle_activity values ( 2,  95, '021', 'R12', 30, 1);
insert into account_cycle_activity values ( 2,  92, '021', 'R12', 30, 1);

create table card_account (account_id number, cycle_ctr number);
insert into card_account values ( 1,   2 );
insert into card_account values ( 2,   2 );
insert into card_account values ( 2,  13 );
insert into card_account values ( 2,  13 );
insert into card_account values ( 2,   9 );
insert into card_account values ( 2, 101 );
insert into card_account values ( 2,  99 );
insert into card_account values ( 2,  96 );
insert into card_account values ( 2,  93 );
```

---

**Edit:** Modified version with `count()` instead of `lag()`, added `range` part and moved part of `where` conditions.

```
with aca as (  
  select a.*, count(1) over (
        partition by account_id, activity_type_code, activity_group_code
        order by cycle_ctr range between 6 preceding and 1 preceding ) as pcc
    from account_cycle_activity a 
    where activity_type_code in ('011', '021', '007') and activity_group_code = 'R12' 
      and cycle_activity_count = 1 )
select *
  from aca join card_account ca 
      on ca.account_id = aca.account_id and ca.cycle_ctr - 1 = aca.cycle_ctr
  where pcc = 0 and cycle_activity_amount > 25
```

Comment: Important. I noticed, that something goes wrong when I add row ( 2,   7, '011', 'R12', 30, 1) to table account_cycle_activity. I'm trying to correct query.

Comment: Modified, actual version of query at the end of answer.